# XML file is created only once not every time when application is executed

Tags: android, xml, file

I'm trying to generate XML file on sdcard. I've added user permission in Manifest file but when I plug my phone though usb and run the application in eclipse then for the first time xml file gets created but when I again run application through phone only or through eclipse then it doesn't gets created. For the file to get created I've to reconnect my phone through usb and in that also it gets created only once. Please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView  myTextView;
     EditText E1;
     EditText E2;
     EditText E3;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    E1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    E2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    E3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
    try {
         docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
         Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Class");
         doc.appendChild(rootElement);
         Element student = doc.createElement("Student");
         rootElement.appendChild(student);
         Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");                                   firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(E1.getText().toString()));
            student.appendChild(firstname);

         Element Email = doc.createElement("Email");
         Email.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(E2.getText().toString()));
         student.appendChild(Email);

         Element Roll = do c.createElement("Roll_No");
         Roll.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(E3.getText().toString()));
         student.appendChild(Roll);
         TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
         DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

         File FF=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//new.xml");
         try {
        FF.createNewFile();
           } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           }

         StreamResult result = new StreamResult(FF);
         transformer.transform(source, result);  
          }
         catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {   
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
         catch (TransformerException e) {               
          e.printStackTrace();}  
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                }
    });

   b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Close the application
           finish(); }});
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're catching the exception and ignoring it. That's not good practice, and that's why you don't know what the error is:

```
        File FF=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//new.xml");
        try {
            FF.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

the line

```
FF.createNewFile();
```

is throwing an exception because you can't create a new file if it already exists. Either delete it first or open it to overwrite it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileAlreadyExistsException.html

Use this code instead:

```
File FF=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//new.xml");
try {
    if (FF.exists());
        FF.delete();
    FF.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle the error here! don't ignore it. Either throw the exception all the way, or log it, or something.
    throw e;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code given by you now the file is not all getting created.

Comment: Did an exception get thrown? Supply the logcat please.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with FF.createNewFile(); . This function return false if the file already exists so that's why it creates only one.

Give a look at here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_createnewfile.htm